# Merge rows in a pandas data frame that occur within 30 days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following pandas data frame:

```
df_raw = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,1,1,2,2], "date": [pd.Timestamp(2002,1,1), pd.Timestamp(2002,1,28), pd.Timestamp(2002,2,1), pd.Timestamp(2003,5,5),pd.Timestamp(2003,5,28)],"value_1": [10,20,30,40,50], "value_2": [60,70,np.nan,np.nan,100]})
```

What I want to achieve is the following:

1. Rows which have the same id and whose dates are maximum 30 days from each other need to be merged.
2. The merging will happen in a way that the values from the row whose date is more recent will be taken as well as the date.
3. If in the more recent row there are missing values the values should be taken from the row whose date is less recent.
4. For each row that can be merged, always check whether we can merge the row with a row that has more recent date. If it has, merge it with that one.
5. Maximum merge two rows. If two rows are merged, do try to merge them with the next row if even the row is also within the 30 days range.

So, the resulting data from should be:

```
df_processed = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,1,2], "date": [pd.Timestamp(2002,1,1), pd.Timestamp(2002,2,1), pd.Timestamp(2003,5,28)], "value_1": [10, 30,50], "value_2": [60, 70,100]})
```

Disclaimer: This is a simplified version of what I truly want to achieve, so I may have some follow up questions.

Comment: I don't understand your logic. You say `values from the row whose date is more recent will be taken as well as the date.` Yet despite  2002 January 28th being within 30 days of 2002 January 1st, your output takes 2002-01-01 date and values.

Comment: @ALollz You are completely right that didn't make any sense. I had a typo and I changed the 3rd row date to be `pd.Timestamp(2002,2,1)` instead of `pd.Timestamp(2002,3,1)`. Let me now if you want me to clarify anything or if you think that something seems off.

Comment: So the first row can be merged with the second but they are not because the second row can be merged with the third (the third has a more recent date). I think that the rest should be more or less clear.

Comment: I think you need to loop, the calculation for one row impacts all other calculations. Perhaps someone else has a better idea.

Comment: What if we simplify the whole thing and make it like this:

1. Merge rows that have dates that are within 30 days and take the values and the date from the more recent row.
2. Unless the values in the more recent row are NaN, then just propagate from the less recent.